# Programmatically update Web.config configSource from global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-config, global-asax

I have a Web.config that has this section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    ...
    <client configSource="local.config" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I would like to change the configSource to a different file from within the Global.asax Application_Start() method based on the execution path of the app.

I think can get the existing configuration using this, but I don't know what to do next:

```
var filemap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = configFilePath };
var oldConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(filemap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var serviceModelSectionGroup = System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(oldConfig);
```